# How do I just print the doubles from a text file with both doubles and strings?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, double

I am attempting to take the text file below and get only the first column of numbers out in order to average. them However, I cant even get the numbers to print because there are also strings in the text file that come before the doubles, making my nextLong() fail immediately.
The code I have so far is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class cancer{

public static void main(String[] args) throws InputMismatchException, FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("trainingDataset.txt"));
    inFile.useDelimiter(",");
    List<Float> arr=new ArrayList<Float>();
     while(inFile.hasNext()){
         float token1 = inFile.nextFloat();
            arr.add(token1);
            }
     inFile.close();
     Float[] tempsArray = arr.toArray(new Float[0]);
        for (Float s : tempsArray) {
          System.out.println(s);
        }
}

}
```

But I get this output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Unknown Source)
    at cancer.main(cancer.java:13)
```

I know I am getting this error because of the strings that come before the doubles. I need to just get the numbers so I can average them and I dont know how. Please Help!

Here is the text file:
[trainingDataset.txt]
 http://txt.do/5w3em

Comment: Use a CSV reading library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ignore lines whereby the first value is not numeric. i.e. Read each line as a string instead of a float and then try to convert the line to a float.  If this fails due to a numberformatexception ignore the line and move onto the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Your file looks like CSV(comma separated values) file. You can do the following:

1. Remove comments from file(those lines who are starting with "//").
2. Try to use any CSV parser(for example:
       https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVParser.html).